# How to send Ajax POST request on https

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, https

I'm trying to make an Ajax POST request, but I keep getting a 404 error "GET https://www.test.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fapi%2ftest%2fsave 404 (Not Found)"
Don't know if it is because the site has https?

This is the code I have used:

```
var params = { name: "Test"};
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.test.com/api/test/save', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(reponse);
    }

};
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Comment: No, if the target site would not support HTTPS, your browser would not be able to create a working connection to it in the first place. Without working HTTPS, you would never get so far that you could get a 404.

Comment: You specified request method POST, but the error message says GET … figure out why that happens, whether your script does not try to make the correct request in the first place, or the target redirects the request, …

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your backend / API is set up to require authentication and if a request is received without authentication, it redirects to the login page. You can see this in your error response:

"GET **https://www.test.com/login.aspx**?ReturnUrl=%2fapi%2ftest%2fsave 404 (Not Found)"

But the other problem is that you don't have a login page! So that explains the 404 Not Found response.

Either disable authentication on your API for testing, or include authentication / credentials in your Ajax request.

Comment: will it work if I also send the _RequestVerificationToken with the request? Though I don't know how to do this...